# Procedure call inside another procedure in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, procedure

I am using tasm and am trying to call a procedure inside another procedure. However, when the program returns from the second procedure, instead of returning to the point at which it was called, the IP is set to 0000. Can someone explain me why does this happen?
Here is a part of the code:

main procedure:

```
MAIN    PROC    FAR ; main proc MUST be FAR

ASSUME  CS:COD1,DS:DATA1,SS:STCK
PUSH    DS      ;save DS on stack for OS return
XOR     AX,AX   ;
PUSH    AX      ;put 0 on stack for OS return
MOV     AX,DATA1
MOV     DS,AX   ;load data Segement register
CALL    PLAY
RET             ; return to OS

MAIN    ENDP
```

First called procedure:

```
PLAY PROC NEAR
RPT:

MOV     AH,00H ;read ch from stdin
INT     16H
CMP     AH,48H
JE      UP
CMP     AH,4BH
JE      LEFT
CMP     AH,50H
JE      DOWN
CMP     AH,4DH
JE      RIGHT
CMP     AH,01H
JE      ESCAPE

UP:
CALL    MOVEUP
JMP     RPT

DOWN:
CALL    MOVEDOWN
JMP     RPT

LEFT:
CALL MOVELEFT
JMP RPT

RIGHT:
CALL MOVERIGHT
JMP RPT

ESCAPE:
RET

PLAY ENDP
```

Model of second called procedure:

```
MOVEUP PROC NEAR    ;tries to update position of player if down key pressed
PUSH    DX
PUSH    AX
PUSH    SI  ;save all general registers to stack

MOV     AL,X    ;compute index for current position
MOV     DL,15   
MUL     DL
MOV     DL,Y    
MOV     DH,0
ADD     AX,DX
MOV     SI,AX
PUSH    SI  ;save it for later


MOV     DL,  X  ;current x coord
MOV     DH,  Y  ;current y coord
SUB     DL,  1
MOV     NEWX,DL ;new x coord
MOV     NEWY,DH ;new y coord
MOV     AL,NEWX ;store new x coord in AL
MOV     AH,0    ;make ah 0 to "extend" new x on 2B
CMP     AL,0    ;check if new x in bounds (>=0)
JL      NOT_OK_UP

MOV     DL,15   ;compute index of position: index=15*x+y
MUL     DL
MOV     DL,NEWY 
MOV     DH,0
ADD     AX,DX
MOV     SI,AX
MOV     DL,MAZE[SI] ;fetch element on position newx,newy
CMP     DL,1        ;if wall, go to end of procedure(nop)

JE      NOT_OK_UP

MOV     DL,NEWX
MOV     DH,NEWY
MOV     X,DL    ;update x
MOV     Y,DH    ;update y
MOV     MAZE[SI],2  ;update position in maze
POP     SI
MOV     MAZE[SI],0  ;clean up old position
NOT_OK_UP:
POP     SI
POP     AX
POP     DX
RET
MOVEUP ENDP
```

Comment: If we execute a "call" instruction, then the return address will be pushed on the stack and if we execute a "ret" instruction, then the address will be poped from the stack. But if we use a "push" instruction inside of a subroutine without a pop instruction at the end, then the top of the stack does not contains the return address. So if we execute a "ret" instruction before we pop the other values from the stack, then these values will be used as the return address instead. And another problem is to call a subroutine within a subroutine without of controll how many instances we are use.

Comment: To augment Dirk's comment, it's the `PUSH SI` marked `save it for later` that isn't properly popped off again when you jump to `NOT_OK_UP`.

Comment: I modified the code, adding the proper pop and it works now. Thank you very much for the explanation and for pointing out the error!